# How to access cloud host by secondary IP?

Tags: networking, dns, cloud, ip, hosts

Version of Ubuntu is 14.04 and host provider 1and1.com.
I have configured the host with two public IPs and following is the configuration of my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address {2nd IP address}
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast {2nd IP address}
network {2nd IP address ended with 0}
```

and the ifconfig -a output is as follows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:12:68:8e
          inet addr:{Primary IP address}  Bcast:{Primary IP address} Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe12:688e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:210260 (210.2 KB)  TX bytes:343976 (343.9 KB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:12:68:8e
          inet addr:{2nd IP address}  Bcast:{2nd IP address} Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So according to the configuration everything should be fine, but I can not access the 2nd IP externally, the ping is getting request timeout and also if I set the 2nd IP to any domain's A Record, that's not working. How can I access the 2nd IP publicly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you double checked the secondary IP, last time I got this kind of issue, I just misspelled my ip address.

Comment: What is your default gateway?

Comment: @olivierb2 yes I checked that well. I just followed the procedure as per the provider's instruction, is there anything else to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, actually the Firewall was blocking all the Ports for the second IP. I just allowed.